# Can an operating system without api still work?

Tags: operating-systems, api-design

In theory operating system is a special program run by itself without help so that also mean normal program can still run by itself mean that the need for api is not must have so finally can we have an os without api ?

Comment: It just like we need Internet Explorer to install a new browser but in theory we can still install it manually but using Internet Explorer is more convenience

Comment: Lol you understand the joke , right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the other programs sit on top of the operating system(OS) and the OS runs on top of the hardware. The OS provides these programs with basic resources the programs will need to run like CPU, memory and input/output from for e.g. mouse and keyboard. The API is the only way they can get these resources, so normal programs will not be able to work on an OS without API. The new browser analogy is wrong since using IE is just a way to download the new browser files(can do it from command line, without IE). New browser still needs the OS to run.

Comment: Fine you succeed